# Vault: Get key value secrets

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've created this secret backend:

```
$ vault secrets enable -path=openshift kv
$ vault write openshift/postgresql username=tdevhub
$ vault write openshift/postgresql password=password
```

I don't quite figure out how to read `username` and `password` values.

I've tried with:

```
$ vault read openshift/postgresql/password
```

or

```
$ vault kv get openshift/post...
```

By other hand, when I perform this command line:

```
$ vault kv get openshift/postgresql                   
====== Data ======
Key         Value
---         -----
username    tdevhub
```

I'd like to store `username` and `password` into a secret backend. I've realized that a `kv` secret backend only is able to store one key... is it right?

How could I get my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store multiple data with a command like this `vault write openshift/postgresql username=tdevhub password=password`. When you will read at that location both `username` and `password` values will be returned.

Unfortunately, you can't append data to the same location, so when you execute the write again on that path the previous values will be overwritten. If you want to append data later, you have two choice:

1. Read your data each time you need to add a value, and append it manually
2. Use the [KV Version 2](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html) of Vault Key/Value secret engine

Answer (score 6):

you can read secrets using

```
vault kv get -field=password openshift/postgresql
```

or

```
vault kv get -field=username openshift/postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flags `-format json` and `-field=data` to get all the data under a given key properly formatted in JSON. This also filters out the extra details.

```sh
vault kv get -format json -field=data openshift/postgresql
```

The output you would get is -

```json
{
  "username": "tdevhub",
  "password": "password"
}
```